# Error compiling Poco sources for cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, poco

i downloaded poco-1.6-all for windows and im trying to build it for cygwin, im getting this error after performing a make install i need some help because i don't know how to solve this NTDDI_VERSION error:

```
$ make install
make -C /cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation'
mkdir -p /cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/release_static
mkdir -p /cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_static
mkdir -p /cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/release_shared
mkdir -p /cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_shared
** Compiling src/ArchiveStrategy.cpp (debug, shared)
g++  -Iinclude -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/CppUnit/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/CppUnit/WinTestRunner/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/XML/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/JSON/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Util/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Net/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Crypto/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/NetSSL_OpenSSL/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Data/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Data/SQLite/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Data/ODBC/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Data/MySQL/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/MongoDB/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Zip/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/PageCompiler/include -I/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/PageCompiler/File2Page/include -DPOCO_NO_FPENVIRONMENT -DPOCO_NO_WSTRING -DPOCO_NO_SHAREDMEMORY -DPOCO_BUILD_HOST=PB00YCT7  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500  -g -D_DEBUG  -c src/ArchiveStrategy.cpp -o /cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_shared/ArchiveStrategy.o
In file included from c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:35:0,
                 from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:28,
                 from include/Poco/UnWindows.h:90,
                 from include/Poco/Platform_WIN32.h:24,
                 from include/Poco/Foundation.h:102,
                 from include/Poco/ArchiveStrategy.h:23,
                 from src/ArchiveStrategy.cpp:17:
c:\mingw\include\sdkddkver.h:137:8: error: #error The _WIN32_WINNT value does not match NTDDI_VERSION
 #      error The _WIN32_WINNT value does not match NTDDI_VERSION
        ^
In file included from include/Poco/ArchiveStrategy.h:23:0,
                 from src/ArchiveStrategy.cpp:17:
include/Poco/Foundation.h:122:4: error: #error POCO_WIN32_UTF8 and POCO_NO_WSTRING are mutually exclusive.
   #error POCO_WIN32_UTF8 and POCO_NO_WSTRING are mutually exclusive.
    ^
/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/build/rules/compile:53: recipe for target '/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_shared/ArchiveStrategy.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_shared/ArchiveStrategy.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation'
Makefile:69: recipe for target 'Foundation-libexec' failed
make: *** [Foundation-libexec] Error 2
```

Here is also the line i use to compile de code:

```
$ ./configure --config=CYGWIN --omit=NetSSL_OpenSSL,Crypto,Data/ODBC,Data/MySQ --prefix=./_INSTALL
$ make clean
$ make -j4 -nodemos
$ make install
```

Any help with this error will be apreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the MinGW has the `c:\mingw\include\sdkddkver.h` outdated in comparison to your Windows OS version. Take a look to this page:

[Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx)

And check that some `#define`'s are not into the mentioned file. I just used Windows 8.1 and received the same error.

A solution could be to use an updated version from MinGW like [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) or any [Visual Studio version](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)

Comment: This helped me with the solution of the NTDDI error and I also managed to solve the POCO_WIN32_UTF8 error, but now im stuck in this: recipe for target '/cygdrive/c/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/obj/CYGWIN/x86_64/debug_shared/ArchiveStrategy.o'